# Remove duplicate tuples from a list if they are exactly the same including order of items

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples, python-itertools

I know questions similar to this have been asked many, many times on Stack Overflow, but I need to remove duplicate tuples from a list, but not just if their elements match up, their elements have to be in the same order. In other words, `(4,3,5)` and `(3,4,5)` would both be present in the output, while if there were both`(3,3,5)` and `(3,3,5)`, only one would be in the output.

Specifically, my code is:

```
import itertools

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
y = []

for x in itertools.combinations(x,3):
    y.append(x)
print(y)
```

of which the output is quite lengthy. For example, in the output, there should be both `(1,2,1)` and `(1,1,2)`. But there should only be one `(1,2,2)`.

Comment: I think you need permutations rather than combinations?

Comment: You cannot get (2, 2, 1) from `combinations()`, given that input.  You'll need to use `permutations()` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, my mistake. But I tried using `permutations()` and did not get the desired result. I don't want (2,2,1) anywhere in the output. I've revised the order of items in my list so as to give the tuples I want in the order I want, but the question stands.

Comment: @5813 combinations definitely will not give you the desired result because it won't include (1,2,1) and (1,1,2). Ordering things is just a matter of sorting which can be done afterwards - please see my answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`set`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-set) will take care of that:

```
>>> a = [(1,2,2), (2,2,1), (1,2,2), (4,3,5), (3,3,5), (3,3,5), (3,4,5)]
>>> set(a)
set([(1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 4, 5), (3, 3, 5), (4, 3, 5)])
>>> list(set(a))
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 4, 5), (3, 3, 5), (4, 3, 5)]
>>>
```

`set` will remove only *exact* duplicates.

Comment: Bear in mind that set could change the order of the list itself

Comment: In Python 3.6+, list(dict.from_key(a)) to maintain order.

Comment: @pylang: I am getting an error message if I am using your solution. "type object 'dict' has no attribute 'from_key'". I need to sort the list of tuples and also maintain the order. I am using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys()`.  Pardon.   Specifically, `list(dict.fromkeys(a))`

Comment: But it will not keep the order, for the simplest and exact solution check out this answer from @roadrunner
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300501/how-to-remove-duplicate-tuples-from-a-list-in-python/48300720

Answer (score 3):

What you need is unique permutations rather than combinations:

```
y = list(set(itertools.permutations(x,3)))
```

That is, (1,2,2) and (2,1,2) will be considered as same combination and only one of them will be returned. They are, however, different permutations. Use `set()` to remove duplicates.

If afterwards you want to sort elements within each tuple and also have the whole list sorted, you can do:

```
y = [tuple(sorted(q)) for q in y]
y.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do `for` loop, `combinations` gives a generator.

```
x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
y = list(set(itertools.combinations(x,3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will probably do what you want, but it's vast overkill.  It's a low-level prototype for a generator that *may* be added to `itertools` some day.  It's low level to ease re-implementing it in C.  Where `N` is the length of the iterable input, it requires worst-case space `O(N)` and does at most `N*(N-1)//2` element comparisons, regardless of how many anagrams are generated.  Both of those are optimal ;-)

You'd use it like so:

```
>>> x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
>>> for t in anagrams(x, 3):
...     print(t)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 1, 5)
(1, 2, 1)
...
```

There will be no duplicates in the output.  Note:  this is Python 3 code.  It needs a few changes to run under Python 2.

```
import operator

class ENode:
    def __init__(self, initial_index=None):
        self.indices = [initial_index]
        self.current = 0
        self.prev = self.next = self

    def index(self):
        "Return current index."
        return self.indices[self.current]

    def unlink(self):
        "Remove self from list."
        self.prev.next = self.next
        self.next.prev = self.prev

    def insert_after(self, x):
        "Insert node x after self."
        x.prev = self
        x.next = self.next
        self.next.prev = x
        self.next = x

    def advance(self):
        """Advance the current index.

        If we're already at the end, remove self from list.

        .restore() undoes everything .advance() did."""

        assert self.current < len(self.indices)
        self.current += 1
        if self.current == len(self.indices):
            self.unlink()

    def restore(self):
        "Undo what .advance() did."
        assert self.current <= len(self.indices)
        if self.current == len(self.indices):
            self.prev.insert_after(self)
        self.current -= 1

def build_equivalence_classes(items, equal):
    ehead = ENode()
    for i, elt in enumerate(items):
        e = ehead.next
        while e is not ehead:
            if equal(elt, items[e.indices[0]]):
                # Add (index of) elt to this equivalence class.
                e.indices.append(i)
                break
            e = e.next
        else:
            # elt not equal to anything seen so far:  append
            # new equivalence class.
            e = ENode(i)
            ehead.prev.insert_after(e)
    return ehead

def anagrams(iterable, count=None, equal=operator.__eq__):
    def perm(i):
        if i:
            e = ehead.next
            assert e is not ehead
            while e is not ehead:
                result[count - i] = e.index()
                e.advance()
                yield from perm(i-1)
                e.restore()
                e = e.next
        else:
            yield tuple(items[j] for j in result)

    items = tuple(iterable)
    if count is None:
        count = len(items)
    if count > len(items):
        return

    ehead = build_equivalence_classes(items, equal)
    result = [None] * count
    yield from perm(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. Just get permutations, not combinations. Order matters in permutations, and it does not in combinations. Thus (1, 2, 2) is a distinct permutation from (2, 2, 1). However (1, 2, 2) is considered a singular combination of one 1 and two 2s. Therefore (2, 2, 1) is not considered a distinct combination from (1, 2, 2).

You can convert your list y to a set so that you remove duplicates...

```
import itertools

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
y = []

for x in itertools.permutations(x,3):
    y.append(x)
print(set(y))
```

And voila, you are done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) should probably work. A set is basically a container that doesn't contain any duplicated elements.

> Python also includes a data type for sets. A set is an unordered
>   collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership
>   testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support
>   mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and
>   symmetric difference.

```
import itertools

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
y = set()

for x in itertools.combinations(x,3):
    y.add(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: You could also just make y a set and not need to convert it, i.e. `y = set(); ... ; y.add(x)`

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? I'd happily improve my answer.