# How to remove duplicate tuples from a list in python?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list that contains list of tuples as follows.

```
mylist = [['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['xxx', 879], ['zzz', 171], ['yyy', 315]]
```

I want to remove the duplicate tuples from `mylist` and get an output as follows.

```
mylist = [['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['zzz', 171]]
```

It seems like `set` in python does not work for it.

```
mylist = list(set(mylist))
```

Is there any fast and easy way of doing this in python (perhaps using libraries)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: Or if you don't need to preserve order check out [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists).

Comment: I don't believe the question is a duplicate of that specific Q&A, though I'd guess there is a better one out there...

Comment: the reason its not working for you is,  you have a list of list , and a list cannot be added to a set because lists are not hashable .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write code that keeps the first of the sub-lists, dropping the rest. The simplest way to do this is to reverse `mylist`, load it into an `dict` object, and retrieve its key-value pairs as lists again.

```
>>> list(map(list, dict(mylist).items()))
```

Or, using a *list comprehension* -

```
>>> [list(v) for v in dict(mylist).items()]
```

```
[['zzz', 171], ['yyy', 315], ['xxx', 879]]
```

Note, that this answer does not maintain order! Also, if your sub-lists can have more than 2 elements, an approach involving hashing the tuplized versions of your data, as [@JohnJosephFernandez' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300720/4909087) shows, would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the reversals? Also I think this fails for something like `mylist = [['xxx', 879], ['xxx', 200]]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sorry, they're part of an older solution I should have removed. They do nothing there.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have to confess that I did misread the question at first, thinking that the key (first sublist item) was the same, and OP wanted the first, dropping all the other duplicates. Because of that, I reversed the list and sent the entries into a dict, so that, when retrieving back, the last key-value pairs that were inserted, overwriting the previous, were the first pairs in the original list. I hope I made sense!

Comment: Right well I arrived late so haven't followed the evolution of the question, but fact remains that `[list(v) for v in dict([['xxx', 879], ['xxx', 200]]).items()]` is not `list(set(tuple(item) for item in [['xxx', 879], ['xxx', 200]]))` and I think the latter (like John Joseph wrote) is what is wanted. But the OP accepted your answer so I may be wrong! Perhaps this situation never arises in their data anyway

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yup, I was rather surprised myself, I'm not afraid to admit I made a meal of answering! Well, OPs are fickle beasts, I've made the necessary edits and disclaimers, I hope that does for now. ;)

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you want to preserve order. In that case you can keep a set that keeps track of what lists have been added.

Here is an example:

```
mylist = [['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['xxx', 879], ['zzz', 171], ['yyy', 315]]

# set that keeps track of what elements have been added
seen = set()

no_dups = []
for lst in mylist:

    # convert to hashable type
    current = tuple(lst)

    # If element not in seen, add it to both
    if current not in seen:
        no_dups.append(lst)
        seen.add(current)

print(no_dups)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['zzz', 171]]
```

**Note:** Since lists are not hashable, you can add tuples instead to the `seen` set.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it appears to retain the order the elements are encountered in the original list?

Answer (score 6):

The reason that you're not able to do this is because you have a list of lists and not a list of tuples.

What you could do is:

```
mytuplelist = [tuple(item) for item in mylist]
mylist = list(set(mytuplelist))
```

or

```
mylist = list(set(map(tuple, mylist)))
```

Comment: @NickA No, but I do have reason to believe it may be the case based on their output, unless OP clarifies. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Respectfully, you can do so in the Questions comment section.

Comment: @NickA I apologise for jumping the gun! I've edited my answer to be a little more appropriate, and will stop plugging this idea since it apparently doesn't matter much to OP anymore.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ looks great, have a rare +1

Comment: you could also do a
mylist = list(set(map(tuple, mylist)))

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
>>> mylist = [['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['xxx', 879], ['zzz', 171], ['yyy', 315]]
>>> y = []
>>> for x in mylist:
...     if not x in y:
...             y+=[x]
...
>>> y
[['xxx', 879], ['yyy', 315], ['zzz', 171]]
```