# Find all combinations of at least size k to n

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm struggling to figure out the formula for this problem:

Given an array of `n` numbers and a limit `k`, count all non-duplicate combinations that has **at least** size `k`.

E.g.: `A=[1,2,3] k = 2 output = 4 // [1,2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3]`

- The array can contain duplicate numbers.

E.g.: `A=[1,1,2] k = 2 output = 3 // [1,1],[1,2],[1,1,2]` but `[1,2],[2,1], etc.` are not accepted.

I was able to solve it using `backtracking` but TLE. I've been trying to find a formula from problems like find all combinations of `n` or find all combinations of size `k` without success.

I've figured out this table so far:

```
row = k
col = n
   1 2 3 4 5
  ---------
1| 1 2 3 4 5
2|   1 3 6 10
3|     1 4 10
4|       1 5
```

And the formula (not quite what I want) is:

```
combinations of size i with j numbers:
dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + dp[i-1][j-1]
```

```
count(n,k) combinations of size k with n numbers
count(2,1) = 2
count(4,3) = count(3,3) + count(3,2) = 1 + 3 = 4
count(5,2) = count(4,2) + count(4,1) = 6 + 4 = 10
and so on
```

### Update

Based on Oliver Dain's answer, here's the code if you're interested

```py
def count_combinations(n, k):
    count = 0
    for i in range(k, n + 1):
        count += math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(i)*math.factorial(n - i))
    return int(count)
```

Comment: Why isn't ```[2,3]``` included in the answer for ```A=[1,2,3]```?

Comment: I've just fixed that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you need the count, or all distinct sequences?

Comment: The array can contain duplicate entries. No, I can't do that. I'll update the question.

Comment: I need the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First figure out how many *unique* values there are in the array (e.g. in most programming languages you could just throw them into a `set` and then find the size of that set). Let's say there's `u` unique values. Then you're answer is the sum of [u choose p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) for all values of p between `k` and `u` (inclusive on both ends).

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you for the link. That's super helpful! I've figured it out.

Comment: Glad that helps. By the way, note that factorials get big really fast so beware integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

use set to remove the duplicates

see for how set removes duplicates [Remove duplicate tuples from a list if they are exactly the same including order of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416786/remove-duplicate-tuples-from-a-list-if-they-are-exactly-the-same-including-order)

Comment: what does size mean in the count?  I didn't understand that part of the problem